# How can I convert a user-input in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, numerical-integration

I am trying to develop a UDF function in R, which should work like this:

- user write a mathematical equation (eg **2*x + 4**)
- My function should convert the input in a R-function and integrate it with lower/upper limits (**0 and 1**)

so, myfunction(2*x+4) have to solve this problem and show 5 as output.

**What I've tried:**

```
myfunction <- function(x, low, up) {

        user_input <- function(x){}
        res <- integrate(user_input, lower = low, upper = up)
        
return(res)
   }

myfunction(2*x+4, low = 0, up = 1)
```

Error:

> Error in integrate(user_input, lower = low, upper = up) :
> evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

---

sure, I could do the following:

```
integrand <- function(x){2*x+4}
integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = 1)
```

but thats not what I am looking for.

I would be very happy about some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
myfunction <- function(y, low, up) {

        user_input <- as.function(c(alist(x = ), list(substitute(y))))
        res <- integrate(user_input, lower = low, upper = up)
        
return(res)

   }
```

-testing

```
myfunction(2*x+4, low = 0, up = 1)
5 with absolute error < 5.6e-14
```

Comment: Hey @akrun, thank you for your answer. I tried this also, but its just uses "x" as function and ignore the function. The result should be 5

Comment: @Onur I saw only your initial comment and not the edited version (which was not notified).  Updated the answer

Comment: thank you for your time, it works perfectly :) 
But could you maybe explain me the first line of code `user_input <- as.function(c(alist(x = ), list(substitute(y))))` ? I dont get it tbh

Comment: @Onur `alist(x = )` returns a list with key only and value empty (`list(x = )` returns errror as value can't be empty), then we concatenate that list with `y` value (returns a list of length 2 i.e. first the key and the second the value) i.e. substitute will return the exact argument passed into the function as a symbol, this is converted to a function with `as.function`

Comment: @Onur I would suggest you to split up the code to understand i.e. check for `asplit(x=)` and `list(substitute(y))` (if this is done outside the fucntion, it will be just `y`

Comment: great, I think I figured it out know, again - thank you :)